# non-static method matcher(CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I keep running into this error whenever I build projects on Android Studio:

> non-static method matcher(CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context

The error occurs at line 9: `matcher = Pattern.matcher(email);`

This is my code:

```
//Email Validation using Regex

public boolean emailChecker(String email){
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = Pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: no problem, downvote retracted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used Pattern.matcher which is the class name

Use:

```
pattern.matcher(yourinput); //pattern is your compiled pattern variable
```

Also i would suggest the built in pattern in android to avoid any regex errors

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
  return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches())
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that typo. Thanks Kushan this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern object you created

```
matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark it as the answer